# evolution -> thunderbird migration and archive size

Tags: thunderbird, email, evolution, maildir, mbox

I just migrated my email from evolution 3.2.3 to thunderbird. As that version of evolution is already storing email in maildir format I exported all folders by hand into mbox format (from within evolution, doing select all + save as) and then imported them in thunderbird with ImportExportTools. This has somehow caused a *dramatic* size increase of my mail archive. The evolution backup is only 0.5G and after exporting everything to mbox I now have 56G on my hands (so about a factor 100 increase). After importing everything into thunderbird it did not really get smaller. The two archives really contain the same data. Does anyone know how this is possible? I thought that maildir and mbox formats were more or less comparable in performance.

Comment: Well, I really don't know what evolution has been exporting there, but I eventually tried to run the python script from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501182/convert-maildir-to-mbox) on evolutions maildir tree and it gave me an mbox tree of the same size as the maildir tree. Importing that into thunderbird also worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to use an imap account to do the switch. Don't you have one that you could use?